# How to route requests to correct LAN card

Tags: networking, routing

I am trying to make a ping request to a 192.168.1.x address on my network, but the request appears to be routing to the wrong LAN card and timing out;

[image]

I have a VM with 2 LAN cards setup as follows

[image]

My routing table is

[image]

Shouldn't I be able to do this without static routes?

Comment: It is not a routing issue from the point of view of your source machine. As you have an interface with an address belonging to your target subnet and a routing table entry to reflect this, the packets will have been routed correctly. Check for active firewalls/ACLs on your source and target, and that the target is up and has net connectivity. Also check the vm host connectivity and virtual nic settings.

Comment: `Destination host unreachable` means the ARP request did not return a MAC address for `192.168.1.4`. You have the correct route (#9 in your routing table), there's another issue with your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd leave this in case anyone else has the same issue. Both these network adapters were virtual adapters under ESXi.I simply removed them and then added them again, and the problem disappeared. Not sure why!